# Remove all content using pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm looking for a way to remove the entire content of a web page using pure Javascript -- no libraries.

I tried:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = "whatever";
```

but that doesn't work: it replaces the inside of the `<html/>` element. I'm looking at replacing the entire document, including if possible the `doctype` and `<?xml` declaration.

Comment: `location = 'about:blank'`

Comment: To what end? Javascript works on the DOM which is a higher-level than the underlying HTML serialization (i.e. where the `<?xml` and doctype are).

Comment: @Yi Jiang This works, but I actually want to stay on the same domain...

Comment: @Yi Jiang +1 for a good suggestion (if you want to leave it as an answer, I'll remove my edit :) )

Comment: I mourn the passing of the static web page, with the associated ability to look at the source code of any web page to understand how it was constructed and how it all works.

Comment: Constructing web pages dynamically, with no content: https://codepen.io/applecrazy/pen/mEJjXr

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think a browser rightfully assumes a page with content-type `text/html` will always be a web page - so whilst you may do something like...

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

It will still have some HTML hanging around.

You could try...

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
```

...which left me with `<html></html>`.

[Yi Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313758/yi-jiang) did suggest something clever.

```
window.location = 'about:blank';
```

This will take you to a blank page - an internal mechanism provided by most browsers I believe.

I think however the best solution is to use `document.open()` which will clear the screen.

Comment: The first updated answer was half of what I was looking for. But I guess changing the `doctype` is asking a bit too much...

Comment: @passcod Once you change the doctype too, you are changing how the browser will render your HTML/CSS. This will *probably* entail a page reload. I don't think you can change a doctype on the fly.

Comment: @alex changing **window.location** to **'about:blank'** has a problem with IE specialy IE10 because some addons when detect **about:blank** page fill it with their contents

Comment: My solution seems more appropriate, and avoids the `about:blank` hack.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen I forgot to add that to my answer, as I suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241397/remove-all-content-using-pure-js/4241420?noredirect=1#comment28883886_4241519).

Answer (score 4):

```
var i = document.childNodes.length - 1;

while (i >= 0) {
  console.log(document.childNodes[i]);
  document.removeChild(document.childNodes[i--]);
}
```

Removes everything (doctype also) on FF 3.6, Chrome 3.195, and Safari 4.0.  IE8 breaks since the child wants to remove its parent.

---

Revisiting a while later, could also be done like this:

```
while (document.firstChild) {
  document.removeChild(document.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Great, but you still can't change the doctype... which doesn't matter much. Firefox crashed when I tried...

Comment: Is your question "How to change the doctype" or "Remove all content with pure JS"?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Dotoro's article on the document.clear method](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcxfnth.php), they (since it's deprecated) recommend calling `document.open` instead, which clears the page, since it starts a new stream.

This way, you avoid the nasty `about:blank` hack.

Answer (score 3):

One can remove both the `<html>` element ([`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)) and the doctype ([`document.doctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/doctype)).

```
document.doctype.remove();
document.documentElement.remove();
```

Alternatively, a loop can be used to remove all children of the `document`.

```
while(document.firstChild) document.firstChild.remove();
```

[`document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open) or [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) work as well.

Answer (score 1):

After the page has already fully loaded:

```
document.write('');
document.close();
```

Comment: You could just use `document.open()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do it

```
document.clear()  //deprecated

window.location = "about:blank"  //this clears out everything
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, but I did try it on jsbin.com which may be doing something else behind the scenes.

Comment: @alex ..yeah I just realized document.clear() has been deprecated.

Comment: @John Hartsock changing **window.location** to **'about:blank'** has a problem with IE specialy IE10 because some addons when detect **about:blank** page fill it with their contents

Comment: Five years later, it is not so important that lots of things still don't work in IE, since MS has stopped development of IE in favor of Edge.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML='';
document.open();
```

The Document.open() method opens a document for writing.
if you dont use open method, you cant modify Document after set innerhtml to empty string

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will still leave the doctype node hanging around, but:

`document.documentElement.remove()`

or the equivalent

`document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].remove()`

Answer (score 0):

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dexterity/mpr3kw6v/3/)

If youre using jQuery here's your solution

```
<div id="mydiv">some text</div>
<br><br>
<button id="bn" style="cursor:pointer">Empty div</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#bn', function() {
  $("#mydiv").empty();
  $("#bn").empty().append("Done!");
});
</script>
```

If youre using javascript here's your solution

```
<div id="purejar">some text</div>
<br><br>
<button id="bnjar" onclick="run()" style="cursor:pointer">Empty div</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var run = function() {
  var purejar = document.getElementById("purejar");
  var bn = document.getElementById("bnjar");
  purejar.innerHTML = '';
  bn.innerHTML = 'Done!';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Im just curious as to why you'd want to do that. Now theres no way that I know of to replace absolutely everything down to the doctype declaration but if you are wanting to go to those lengths why not redirect the user to a specially crafted page that has the template you need with the doctype you need and then fill out the content there?

EDIT: in response to comment, what you could do is strip all content then create an iframe make it fill the entire page, and then you have total control of the content. Be aware that this is a big hack and will probably be very painful - but it would work :)

Comment: To all who asked the reasons... This seemed like an easy way of stripping everything out and starting from scratch in a userscript... I can include whatever JS code I want, and it will run in the page, not in a sandbox. The `doctype` thing is for when I want to use xhtml on a html website.

Comment: In fact, Steve's solution is great... just have to tweak some stuff to include the `doctype`...

Comment: It's for userscripts. Ofc I don't need IE support. =)

Comment: @passcod - Changing the doctype is pointless. You wont end up with an XML document - only an HTTP content-type can do that. And if your building your DOM in javascript, you're not going to validate it either.

Answer (score -3):

REMOVE EVERYTHING BUT --- !DOCTYPE html ---

```
var l = document.childNodes.length;    
while (l > 1) { var i = document.childNodes[1]; document.removeChild(i); l--; }
```

TESTED ON FIREFOX WEB INSPECTOR - childNodes[1] IS --- !DOCTYPE html ---