# how can I clear the contents of a UIWebView/WKWebView?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a webview that can be cycled through different URLs. When I switch from one to the other I want the old web page to disappear before loading the next one. How can I do this without re allocating the webview?

If I try to `[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];` and load my URL in the same function the previous web page still remains:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.pageURL]];
```

EDIT: this apparently isn't clear enough for you. the below code doesn't clear the webview, it displays the previous page until the new one is loaded:

```
- (void) startLoadOfNextURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    // clear:
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil]; //DOESNT WORK  

    // Load real next URL
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: can you pl. refer to the below link which discusses how to clear the webview  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576154/how-to-clear-a-uiwebview

Comment: it doesn't answer my question

Comment: you need to clear the old webpage and load the new one right, i have tried the below approach mentioned an the link and it has helped me              Try setting the URL to about:blank and reload the page.

Comment: read my question again - I want to clear the page and immediately load a webpage i.e (webpage -> click -> blank -> new page)

Comment: Can't you just hide the webview when you "click" and show it again when the delegate method reports that it's loaded?

Comment: @Halpo Did you find a solution to this problem.  I am having a similar issue when dequeuing a UITableViewCell that contains a WKWebView.  While the cell's url is loaded, the data (page) of the "dequeued" cell is still displayed.  I am thinking of removing the Webview and adding a new one at this stage.  (Seeing that the UITableViewCell contain more controls than just the webview.)

Comment: @CarienvanZyl I think the only reliable way is to re-init the web view

Answer (score 32):

You can write the code below while your controller dismisses.

```swift
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string:"about:blank")!))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can make it load a blank page

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

Comment: I know, but I want to clear the webview then immediately load a new page

Comment: This answer is the key to your problem. Just load `about:blank` to *clear* the page and then load whatever you need to.

Comment: but I cant do both in the same function (the page doesnt clear, please just read my question)

Answer (score 12):

Use JavaScript instead.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.remove()")
```

Answer (score 11):

The following code clears the screen and then navigates

**Swift**

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.remove()") { (_, _) in
    self.webView.load(urlRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## To clear old contents of webview

When you call `- loadHTMLString:baseURL:` it doesn't block until the load is complete.  Once it records your request, it returns and loads in the background.

As a result, you would need to wait for the first load to finish before kicking off a new load request.

With `UIWebView` you would use `UIWebViewDelegate`'s 
`- webViewDidFinishLoad:`.

With WKWebView you would use `WKNavigationDelegate`'s 
`- webView:didFinishNavigation:`

Another approach if you really wanted to clear the contents without a delegate method would be to use JavaScript (eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/4241420/3352624).  Then for UIWebView you could invoke `- stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`.  That method will block execution until the JavaScript executes and returns.

For `WKWebView`, you would need to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894786/3352624 since its `- evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:` doesn't block.

## To make old contents "disappear"

If you really just want to make "the old web page to disappear", you could cover the content area of the webview with a blank UIView temporarily.  You could hide the contents when you initiate the load and then show the contents using the delegate methods above after the load completes.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift**

```
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "about:blank")!))

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
   //Load request or write code here
})
```