# Unsafe assignment to innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I was trying to get an add on for Firefox signed by Mozilla so I could use it on the stable version of firefox and I'm getting this validation issue.

Can someone help me understand what it is?

```sh
Unsafe assignment to innerHTML

Warning: Due to both security and performance concerns, 
    this may not be set using dynamic values which have not been adequately sanitized. 
    This can lead to security issues or fairly serious performance degradation.
    datetime.js line 4 column 5
```

```
function updateClock(){
    var doc=window.content.document
    var dt = new Date();
    doc.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
}

setInterval(updateClock, 0);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to purge innerHTML from a Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579400/best-way-to-purge-innerhtml-from-a-firefox-extension)

Comment: `toLocaleTimeString()` doesn't return HTML so I don't think you even want to modify HTML tags. You possibly want to modify the text contents of an existing node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dt.toLocateTimeString()` return a `String` instead of `HTML`.
Instead of, use `innerText` or `textContent`:

```
doc.getElementById("datetime").innerText = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
doc.getElementById("datetime").textContent = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
```

Comment: What when you need to actually add HTML tags?

Comment: `innerHTML` will do the job

`doc.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = "<div>test</div>"`